# convert website URL into PDF file

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert website URL (eg: www.google.com) into PDF file. But I am not getting expected output.

I tried to get response from url.  But I have no idea how to parse it and write it into PDF.

I can use the following utilities.

1. itextsharp dll
2. Aspose utility

Can anyone guide me how can I achieve to covert into PDF using above utility from given url in c# console application.

Really appreciate your help as I am stuck with this for last two days...

If openxml works that is also fine..

Below is the code that I have tried.

```
     WebRequest wReq = WebRequest.Create("http://www.economist.com/news/united-states/21647625-150-years-after-end-civil-war-states-were-once-confederate-remain");
            WebResponse wRsp = null;

            try
            {
                wRsp = wReq.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} exception caught.", e);
            }

            string strPDFpath = @"D://MyPDF.pdf";
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)wRsp).StatusDescription);
            Stream sRsp = wRsp.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader sRdr = new StreamReader(sRsp);
            string sHtml = string.Empty;
            sHtml = sRdr.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(sHtml);
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(sHtml);

            using (StringWriter strWrite = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(strWrite))
                {
                    //To Export all pages
                    StringReader read = sr;
                    Document targetDoc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
                    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(targetDoc);                        
                    PdfWriter.GetInstance(targetDoc, new FileStream(strPDFpath, FileMode.Create));
                    targetDoc.Open();
                    htmlparser.Parse(read);
                    targetDoc.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

I am getting an error "Illegal characters in Path." on below line.

```
    htmlparser.Parse(read);
```

Comment: Please post the code you're written and errors your having with it.

Comment: In this format your question is too broad. You can read a tutorial, for both components, try to do something and report where is your problem

Comment: I am not able to post my code now as I don't have my laptop now...steps follwed...web request and web response in a sring variable.... After parsing string I am writing it in a PDF which is actually looks like text format... It is not looks like webpage

Comment: Without your laptop, you cant even test the solutions.  Perhaps you should get back to us when you are prepared.

Comment: did you mean that you are creating a pdf, but it looks like html code?  If so, you need to render the text into the pdf.  I'm pretty sure that both iTextSharp and Aspose have a render as html method.

Comment: Updated my code, Do you have any input.